# Encryption of multiple disk partitions

Tags: encryption, install

Recently I have tested many many Linux distros, and I must say to me Elementary seems to be the best in all aspects. I would love to use it, but there is an issue that bothers me:

I would love to be able to encrypt separate partitions with one passphrase (the way it is done in Anaconda installer/Fedora or MX linux). Now I have an option to encrypt all disk, but I want to have separate root, /home, swap partitions all encrypted, leaving /boot /boot/efi unencrypted, so when I start the PC it would ask me for a passphrase to unlock all those partitions (disk). How do I do that? I could not figure that out, and I’m not experienced enough to try some command line stuff.

Maybe you could implement similar functionality to Elementary OS installer as the Anaconda installer have for encryption? Give more options, more flexibility?

Thanks guys!